# Image magick padding font

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to put a label with a transparent background on an image, which works, but there is an issue with padding. The text is too close to the top of the transparent background. I wanted to add some padding to it, but I can't seem to get it to work. I know I could probably do it with draw for the background instead, but the length of the label changes all the time. I guess I could estimate the size I need based on character length, but is there a more simple way in image magick?

I tried to search for an option to maybe change line height or something, but just found spacing between words, chars, or lines instead.

Any ideas?

```
Convert input.jpg -fill white -undercolor 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .75)' -font Helvetica -pointsize 48 -gravity south -annotate +0+35 " Blah blah blah " output.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `label` to create your label, then `splice` some extra lines on top, then composite that onto your image. It is a bit ugly but not too complicated.

```
convert -background 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .75)'          \
        -fill white -font Helvetica -pointsize 48 \
        label:" Blah blah blah " -splice 0x10     \
        input.jpg                                 \
        +swap -gravity south                      \
        -geometry +0+10 -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

Or you can do it the other way around and preserve the metadata:

```
convert input.jpg                                      \
       \( -background 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .75)' -fill white \
          -font Helvetica -pointsize 48                \
          label:" Blah blah blah " -splice 0x10        \
       \) -gravity south -geometry +0+10 -composite result.jpg
```

Comment: ahh its that splice! Thanks, this helped a lot

Comment: Pleasure! Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be a solution for adding a padding on all sides of a transparent text image

Use:

```
 
 -gravity southeast -splice 20x20  -gravity northwest -splice 20x20
```

This solution works good for me

Without Padding:

```
convert -background "rgba(0, 255 ,0, 0.7)"   \ 
    -font "Lobster-Regular.ttf" -pointsize "60" \ 
    -fill "#FFFFFF" label:"PROMOTE ANYTHING"  \
     heading.png
```

[image: <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/njglnz94qz12ojy/sub_heading.png"></image>]

With Padding:

```
 convert -background "rgba(0, 255 ,0, 0.7)"  \ 
    -font "Lobster-Regular.ttf" -pointsize "60" \ 
    -fill "#FFFFFF" label:"PROMOTE ANYTHING" \
    -gravity southeast -splice 20x20  -gravity northwest -splice 20x20 \
     heading.png
```

[image]